# How to add a widget from servlet class?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets

How can I add a widget object to window from a servlet class in GWT?

Thanks,
Vara Kumar PJD

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

GWT widgets will not be available for servlets at the server side. They are available at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is truly Impossible.

But still as a Suggestion i can say that,

If you are making any RPC Calls to & fro the Server, you can pass parameters from Server to client side regarding which widget to load. And thus in the Success/Failure Events of a RPC call, you can make the widget to load.

For example, a Alert Box or Dialog Box Widget in case of an Error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean "How to add widget dynamically from servlet (server side code)?"

i think you need to send some message from client to server and then server send something back to client browser.

there are no reason to add widget dynamically from server side.
if your application is bandwidth sensitive please try to use css resource,resource bundle

hope this help

```
public void addScript(String uniqueId, String url)
 { 
    Element e = DOM.createElement("script"); 
    DOM.setAttribute(e, "language", "JavaScript"); 
    DOM.setAttribute(e, "src", url); 
    scriptTags.put(uniqueId, e); 
    DOM.appendChild(RootPanel.get().getElement(), e); 
  }
```